# Custom email templates sales_email_order_items has no style

Tags: magento2

I made a custom email template from the backend of Magento. When I add

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
```

I see the item table, but no styling and there is no formatting, just a basic table

How do I add styling to this?

Answer (score 0):

some email clients wipe out styles. is it in any clients? gmail/outlook/mailapp, etc?

Comment: The tables before that like Shipping Information or Shipping Method the table is styled I see the gray table head.